# How to consume REST with Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I'm new to angular, so I was following Recipes with Angular.js, more specifically "Consuming RESTful APIs" part.

I have working REST service at localhost:8080/test/categories which returns this JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"name1"},{"id":2,"name":"name2"},{"id":3,"name":"name3"}]
```

This is my web page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR" id="ng-app" ng-app="categories">
<head>
    <title>REST TEST</title>
    <script src='/resources/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/resources/js/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/resources/js/angular-resource.min.js'></script>
    <script src='/resources/js/custom-ang.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="CatController as cat">
    <div class="row placeholders">
        <h4>First</h4>
        <h4>{{"ID: " + cat.categories[0].id}}</h4>
        <h4>{{"Name: " + cat.categories[0].name}}</h4>

        <h4>All</h4>
        <div ng-repeat="category in cat.categories">
            <h4>{{"Name: " + category.name}}</h4>
            <h4>{{"ID: " + category.id}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is custom-ang.js:

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('categories', [ 'ngResource' ]);

app.factory('Category', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8080/test/categories/:id');
});

app.controller('CatController', function($scope, Category) {
    Category.query(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.categories = data;
    });
});
})();
```

But when I run this all I get on my page is:

```
First
ID:
Name:
All
```

Consol log returns appropriate object array.

I'm probably doing something wrong but I can't find it, can someone help me with this issue? Thanks

Comment: console.log(data); what does it gives you in console?

Comment: I tired that, but the page stays the same, should I remove it anyway? I think I saw that somewhere, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Ahmad I do not know how to use that command, but I will find out and edit my question

Comment: @trainoasis definitely don't do that. Self executing function brings along a lot of goodness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you miss a thing at your resource configuration. You shoud try to use this:

```
var Category = $resource(
       'http://localhost:8080/test/categories/:id',
       {id:'@id'});
```

There is also a problem when using the list in the HTML content. You should do the following things since you put the categories in the context:

```
<h4>First</h4>
<h4>{{"ID: " + categories[0].id}}</h4>
<h4>{{"Name: " + categories[0].name}}</h4>

<h4>All</h4>
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <h4>{{"Name: " + category.name}}</h4>
    <h4>{{"ID: " + category.id}}</h4>
</div>
```

See the sample "Credit card resource" to more hints at this link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

Your `custom-ang.js` file should look like this:

```
(function() {
    angular.module('categories', [ 'ngResource' ])
    .factory('Category', function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:8080/test/categories/:id');
    })    
    .controller('CatController', function($scope, Category) {
        $scope.categories = Category.query(); // this is the key
    });
})();
```

And modify your `html`:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
```

Comment: I would also mention the controller as syntax

Comment: @CallumLinington what you mean?

Comment: He is using controller as syntax in the view, but his controller function puts bindable properties onto the scope object and not the controller function context.

Answer (score -1):

You are using the "controller as" syntax and referring to your data through your controller, but the controller is placing the data in the `$scope`. Do:

```
app.controller('CatController', function($scope, Category) {
    var self = this;
    Category.query(function(data) {
        self.categories = data;
    });
});
```

EDIT: As per the comment, `this` did not refer to the correct object (the controller).

Comment: Surely you have to take reference to `this` in the controller scope first? so `function ($scope, Category) { var vm = this; ...... }`

Answer (score -1):

Why did you add "/:id" ? You don't need to do this :

```
$resource('http://localhost:8080/test/categories');
```

Also, you must change : `{{"Name: " + category.content}}` by `{{"Name: " + category.name}}`

Comment: Oh, right, this second one is copy/paste error, I will edit that